# ¿Cómo inicializar una variable agrupando por los distintos valores?

Tags: r

Quiero marcar (1,2,3...) cada distinto valor que tenga una variable, pero no se me ocurre una forma eficiente de hacerlo (se me ocurre encadenar varios for, pero creo que es muy poco eficiente).

Por ejemplo:

```
datos = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b","c", "c", "c")
df = as.data.frame(datos)
```

Quiero que quede de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea sin usar bucles?

Gracias, un saludo

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, revisate [ask] para saber cómo formular una buena pregunta y que ésta sea bien recibida en la comunidad. Le falta algo de investigación a tu pregunta, ¿Que has probado?. Te recomiendo tambien que hagas el [tour] y así también obtienes tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma bien sencilla:

```
datos$cont <- sequence(rle(as.character(datos$datos))$lengths)
```

- Con `rle(as.character(datos$datos))$lengths` obtenemos las longitudes de cada grupo
- con sequence() generamos las numeraciones de 1 a cada longitud.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una posible solución usando apply.

```
 datos = data.frame(datos=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b","c", "c", "c"))

 unicos <-unique(datos)

 numerar <- function(uni, datos){
   n <- sum(datos==uni)
   vec <- c(1:n)
   return(vec)}

 out.list <- apply(unicos, 1,FUN=numerar, datos)

 cont <- unlist(out.list, use.names = FALSE)

 cbind(datos,cont )

    datos cont
 1     a    1
 2     a    2
 3     b    1
 4     b    2
 5     b    3
 6     b    4
 7     c    1
 8     c    2
 9     c    3
```